# Force child component to rerender (React)

Tags: reactjs

I have a third party component that I need to completely re-render when the props I pass to it change.

How do I get it to re-render completely without getting the vendor to update their code? (Seems to be a shortcoming in their code)

I've tried `this.forceUpdate()` and it doesn't fully re-render their component.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the props you want to monitor as the `key` of the component you're trying to re-render.

e.g. `<ThirdPartyComponent key={this.props.foo} ...>`

--

If you need to monitor more then one prop, consider combining them in a way that represents their purpose (and if one changes, they both change). The below assumes they're both strings.

e.g. `` <ThirdPartyComponent key={`${this.props.foo}/${this.props.bar}`} ...> ``